# Modeling $k$-logistic diffusion process

Tags: diffusion

I'm trying to model a diffusion process characterized by subsequent logistic diffusion processes. To give a better idea of what I'm trying to model, you can take a look at the attached figure. In such a figure, I represented a double-logistic diffusion process, where the function $f(t)$ remains stable, then has a steep increase, then remains stable, then a steep increase, and finally remains stable.

A single [logistic diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) process is usually governed by:
$$ f(t) = \frac{L}{ 1 + \exp(-\kappa(t-t_{0}))},$$

where $L$ is the curve's maximal value, $\kappa$ is the steepness of the curve, and $t_{0}$ is the t-value of the sigmoid's midpoint.

How can I model a process where logistic diffusion processes repeat for $k$ times? Any ideas or references will be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way of dealing with the problem is to view it as a dynamical system and to use phase portraits. Let me rename $f(t) = x(t)$ and rescale things such that $x$ obeys the logistic equation $dx/dt \equiv \dot{x} = - kx(1-x)$. The phase portrait is then a plot of $\dot{x}$ versus $x$. For $k > 0$ this is an inverted parabola:

[image: Phase portrait for logistic equation]

As one can see, the zero at $x=1$ corresponds to a stable equilibrium, often called the carrying capacity in a population dynamics context. The solution of the logistic equation is the sigmoid given in the question,

$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-k(t - t_0))} \; . \quad (1) $$

From this one can see that it takes an infinite amount of time to reach equilibrium, $x=1$. Alternatively, this can be inferred from the integral (or by solving for $t = t(x)$),

$$ t - t_0 = \frac{1}{k} \int_{1/2}^x \frac{dy}{y(1-y)} =  \frac{1}{k} \, \ln \frac{x}{1-x} \; , \quad (2) $$

which diverges for $x \to 1$.

To obtain the behaviour shown in the question (a smoothed staircase function), the phase portrait must be similar to that of a *rotating* plane pendulum. Qualitatively, the phase portrait needs to look as follows:

[image: Phase portrait for smoothed staircase]

This is similar to quasi-periodically replicating parabolae, but in such a way that there are no intermediate zeros (attractors). The closer the minima of $\dot{x}(x)$ are to zero, the flatter will be the plateaux in the graph of $x = x(t)$. The physical analogue is a plane pendulum starting out from an inverted position (unstable equilibrium) with just enough energy to perform a few revolutions until the energy drops adiabatically, whereupon a stable equilibrium is reached.

This can indeed be modelled with a "pendulum equation" of the type

$$  \dot{x} = k \omega_0 \sqrt{1 - (1/k^2) \sin^2 x} \; , \quad (3) $$

which describes the 'wiggly' behaviour of the plot above. The monotonous initial and final pieces of the graph have been attached by replacing the square root by its quadratic Taylor expansions at $x \le - 10$ and $x \ge 10$.

[For a pendulum of length $\ell$, $x(t)$ is the total angle covered in time $t$,  $\omega_0^2 = g/\ell$ is the unperturbed (harmonic) angular frequency and $k$ the elliptic modulus depending on the amplitude of the oscillation. The energy of the pendulum is then $2mg\ell k^2$ with $mg$ the usual gravitational force.] It is important to have $k = 1 + \epsilon$, $0 < \epsilon \ll 1$, [hence $E > 2mg\ell$] to avoid zeros in $\dot{x}$ corresponding to intermediate equilibria. After all, the dynamics should not get stuck before the final plateau in $x(t)$ is reached.

Unfortunately, as is well known from the discussion of the plane pendulum, the differential equation $(3)$ yields an elliptic integral, namely

$$ k \omega_0 t = \int_0^x \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 - (1/k^2) \sin^2 y}} \; , \quad (4) $$

which replaces (2). Solving for $x$ one finds

$$ x(t) = \text{am} (k\omega_0 t, 1/k) \; , \quad (5) $$

with $\text{am}$ denoting the Jacobi amplitude. Maple knows this as JacobiAM, and hence one can plot it straightforwardly (say for k = 1.01):

[image: JacobiAM]

Adding the monotonous bits of the second plot to (3) by hand should yield horizontal asymptotes.

I have tried to model the generic behaviour displayed in Plot 2 by various trigonometric functions. The integrals can often be done, but then one has to worry about correctly continuing inverse trig (arc) functions beyond their fundamental domains, which I found somewhat tedious.

The pendulum analogue works nicely and seems appropriate for a physics site. I reiterate, though, that all one needs in principle is the generic phase portrait shown in Plot 2.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer to my problem!

Comment: Thanks - was an interesting question: Given $x(t)$, what can one say about the phase portrait $\dot{x}(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for a function $f(t)$ with the qualitative behaviour you describe, or for a function with more specific properties (like solving a differential equation)?

If its just the first, you can use a sum of individual logistic functions.  Say you want $N$ kinks, each of height $L_i$, steepness $\kappa_i$, and positions $t_i$.  Then your function could be:

$$
f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{L_i}{1+e^{-\kappa_i(t-t_i)}} = \frac{L_1}{1+e^{-\kappa_1(t-t_1)}} + \frac{L_2}{1+e^{-k_2(t-t_2)}} + \dots
$$

Again, this function has the qualitative features you describe, but is not (to my knowledge) the solution to any particular physical system.

Comment: I'm looking for the second one. :)

Comment: Cool! Could you edit the question to either include the particular model you're looking at or a reference to it?

Comment: The original logistic function $f$ (a single 'kink') given in the question is a solution of the logistic equation $\dot{f} = \kappa f (1 - f/L)$. This is _nonlinear_ (quadratic in $f$), so the superposition principle does _not_ hold: a sum over single kinks (aka 'multi-kink') will not be a solution. This is well known from soliton physics as is the fact that multi-kinks will be an _approximate_ solution if the individual kinks are far apart. For this situation you'd need $t_1 \ll t_2 \ll ...$.

Comment: @TomHeinzl I agree the superposition doesn't solve the logistic equation, no multi-kink function will solve it since the logistic function is its unique bounded solution.  There are ways of combining solitons to form new solutions of non-linear PDEs, for example in sine-Gordon or KdV, although of course not by simple addition.  Without knowing what specific system/differential equation the OP is inquiring about, its impossible to give an exact answer.

Comment: @TomHeinzl and GeoffRyan. Indeed I have $t_{1} << t_{2} << \dots$. However, my problem is not related to a well-known physical system: I'm not a physicist, but I'm trying to model the diffusion of memes in online social network. Usually a meme has a huge and fast diffusion, than sleeps for a while, and then another huge and fast increase in the number of shares.

Comment: @stochazesthai Gotcha. So what exactly are you looking for? Are you looking for a function with some parameters you can fit to data (ex. total # of reblogs) that looks how you describe? Or do you have some numerical model for diffusion on a graph that you're trying to solve? Or something in between? I ask because there are an infinite number of smooth functions that have the behaviour you describe. If you have no quantitative reason to pick one over the other, than I'd say do something easy like the function I suggested above.